# past due task notification email logic

Tags: node.js, email, notifications, cron

I need to implement in node.js, past due tasks mail notification which has to be sent everyday to user about the tasks he missed which were scheduled for the previous day. Since, the user can be from any timezone, what is the most relevant way to store the task's due date/time ? How should the email sending time be decided and automated keeping in the mind the timezones the user could be ?

Answer (score 0):

You should always store dates in Universal Time (UTC) and localize them when showing them to the user. Without any code or what you've tried to do already I'm not sure there's much else to add to this answer. I highly recommend looking at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for dealing with date objects and [adjusting them for time zones](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).